# scheduling notification android

Tags: android, notifications

Hello I am trying to generate notification at a certain time in Android. I am able to generate the notification, but it generates immediately while I want it to generate at a later time. Can anyone suggest where I went wrong.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

long timeinmill = calendar.getTime().getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MakeAppointment.this, MyReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MakeAppointment.this, 0, myIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeinmill, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not subtract current time. See the [AlarmManager#RTC docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC).

```
timeinmill = calendar.getTime().getTime().
```

Comment: You might also want to mention that `Calendar` has the `getTimeInMillis()` method, to simplify that a bit, and that the month is off by one, if they want the current month.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that would be more direct. As for the month number, this is IMHO a common mistake (unless someone comes from C world :), but then there's often a mistake with the year number.

Comment: Thank you guys. It worked, especially that part where month goes off by one.